# How to order an array by keeping certain elements always on top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

I have an array where I want to place certain items always on top. I am getting the response from API as below.

```
const itemInventorylocationTypes = [
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '00d3898b-c6f8-43eb-9470-70a11cecbbd7',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Rummsan'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '1e8cd068-3cfc-4e25-af22-4a8fec3c794d',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Yes'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: 'f78fb228-7d1a-4cad-bde7-956e5f46db69',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Rambo'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: 'ce4a8a4d-a282-424b-bb2a-5a5187db02e0',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Veronica'
    },
    {
       itemInventorylocationId: '87082949-b148-4766-ad1d-148b91a46a79',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Hunnumous'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '0fdaf8eb-07f4-4300-9c20-44f788724c59',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'PerryPerry'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '4f75ed92-68c0-4137-be37-d64ae77653c7',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Dont know why'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '50efa718-6eed-4eff-ad13-305864c1b243',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Its ok'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: 'c7d3275b-cad9-45b2-9065-0fefdf7fc241',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'This is some random thing'
    }
];
```

Now I want the elemts with `Veronica,rambo, Hunnumous,PerryPerry and Rummsan` to appear first and in this order.

To do that I am creating a reference array and then breaking them up using  lodash intersectionWith and differenceWith.

```
const referenceArray = ['Veronica', 'Rambo', 'Hunnumous', 'PerryPerry', 'Rummsan'];
 
export const sortitemInventory = (itemInventorylocationTypes: DropdownOption[]) => {
    const commonElements = _.intersectionWith(itemInventorylocationTypes, referenceArray, (x, y) => x.itemInventorylocationCd == y);
    const differentElements = _.differenceWith(itemInventorylocationTypes, referenceArray, (x, y) => x.itemInventorylocationCd == y);
    console.log(commonElements);
    console.log(differentElements);
    cosnst newArray = [...commonElements, ...differentElements];
};
```

Expected common elemnt to come in order as in referenceArray. But what I am getting is,

```
const itemInventorylocationTypes = [
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '00d3898b-c6f8-43eb-9470-70a11cecbbd7',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Rummsan'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: 'f78fb228-7d1a-4cad-bde7-956e5f46db69',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Rambo'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: 'ce4a8a4d-a282-424b-bb2a-5a5187db02e0',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Veronica'
    },
    {
        itemInventorylocationId: '87082949-b148-4766-ad1d-148b91a46a79',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'Hunnumous'
    },
   {
        itemInventorylocationId: '0fdaf8eb-07f4-4300-9c20-44f788724c59',
        itemInventorylocationCd: 'PerryPerry'
    }
];
```

Is there another approach? I can probably loop by each element and then push it to new array, but just checking if there is a better way.

Comment: `intersectionWith` saves the order of array in the first argument. That's why you need to reorder your `commonElements`.

Comment: Well, you could just `reverse()` the `referenceArray` before you use it as a reference.

Comment: @HaoWu, reversing the referenceArray will result in only the array with strings, not the one with object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const itemInventorylocationTypes=[{Id:"00d3898b-c6f8-43eb-9470-70a11cecbbd7",Cd:"Rummsan"},{Id:"1e8cd068-3cfc-4e25-af22-4a8fec3c794d",Cd:"Yes"},{Id:"f78fb228-7d1a-4cad-bde7-956e5f46db69",Cd:"Rambo"},{Id:"ce4a8a4d-a282-424b-bb2a-5a5187db02e0",Cd:"Veronica"},{Id:"87082949-b148-4766-ad1d-148b91a46a79",Cd:"Hunnumous"},{Id:"0fdaf8eb-07f4-4300-9c20-44f788724c59",Cd:"PerryPerry"},{Id:"4f75ed92-68c0-4137-be37-d64ae77653c7",Cd:"Dont know why"},{Id:"50efa718-6eed-4eff-ad13-305864c1b243",Cd:"Its ok"},{Id:"c7d3275b-cad9-45b2-9065-0fefdf7fc241",Cd:"This is some random thing"}],
      referenceArray = ['Veronica', 'Rambo', 'Hunnumous', 'PerryPerry', 'Rummsan'],
      priority = Object.fromEntries( referenceArray.map((k,i) => [k,i]) )

console.log(priority)

itemInventorylocationTypes.sort((a,b) => 
  priority.hasOwnProperty(b.Cd) - priority.hasOwnProperty(a.Cd)
  || priority[a.Cd] - priority[b.Cd]
)

console.log(itemInventorylocationTypes)
```

Create a `priority` object which maps each `referenceArray` item to it's index.

First `sort` the array based on whether each `Cd` is present in the `priority`.

<sup>(I have removed the `itemInventorylocation` prefix from key names to make it more readable)</sup>

```
priority.hasOwnProperty(b.Cd) - priority.hasOwnProperty(a.Cd)
```

This works because booleans are coerced to numbers when they are subtracted.

```
true - true === 0
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
```

- If `a.Cd` is present in priority and `b.Cd` isn't, the subtraction returns `-1` and `a` is prioritized to `b` in the sorted array
- If both of them are present in priority, then the subtraction returns `0` which is a `falsy` value. Then, the second part of `||` is checked.

If the subtraction returns `0`, sort the items based on their `Cd` value in the `priority` object

You could also use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as `priority`

```js
const itemInventorylocationTypes=[{Id:"00d3898b-c6f8-43eb-9470-70a11cecbbd7",Cd:"Rummsan"},{Id:"1e8cd068-3cfc-4e25-af22-4a8fec3c794d",Cd:"Yes"},{Id:"f78fb228-7d1a-4cad-bde7-956e5f46db69",Cd:"Rambo"},{Id:"ce4a8a4d-a282-424b-bb2a-5a5187db02e0",Cd:"Veronica"},{Id:"87082949-b148-4766-ad1d-148b91a46a79",Cd:"Hunnumous"},{Id:"0fdaf8eb-07f4-4300-9c20-44f788724c59",Cd:"PerryPerry"},{Id:"4f75ed92-68c0-4137-be37-d64ae77653c7",Cd:"Dont know why"},{Id:"50efa718-6eed-4eff-ad13-305864c1b243",Cd:"Its ok"},{Id:"c7d3275b-cad9-45b2-9065-0fefdf7fc241",Cd:"This is some random thing"}],
      referenceArray = ['Veronica', 'Rambo', 'Hunnumous', 'PerryPerry', 'Rummsan'],
      priority = new Map(referenceArray.map((k,i) => [k,i]))

itemInventorylocationTypes.sort((a,b) => 
  priority.has(b.Cd) - priority.has(a.Cd)
  || priority.get(a.Cd) - priority.get(b.Cd)
)

console.log(itemInventorylocationTypes)
```